# Finding a combination of food with certain vitamin values

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

I'm looking for some advice on a nutritional problem I'm working on, of all things. Seeing if there's a particular branch of mathematics that could be useful.  I'm trying to find what quantity of foods I would need to hit a set of target nutritional needs.

For example: if I have three different food types and their vitamin values for $A,B,C$  are  $(10,20,15),\ (5,10,30),\ (20,40,30)$ per gram and the target values for $A, B, C$ are $(1000, 900, 1200)$, what quantity (grams) of each food would I need to buy to roughly hit these values?

What I'm currently doing is summing all the initial starting values of the food, then summing the target values. Next step is to dived the target sum values  by the initial sum values to find a sort of average number of grams I could multiply all the food values by to hit the target.

I've had a little success with this, and I've tried and weighting the values of each food depending on their contribution to the total. But I know there's got to be a more accurate way to go, any ideas?

Comment: This can be written as a [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem

Comment: In linear programming, you create a 'feasibility region.' That's three dimensional shape (in your case) that contains all the solutions, and anything outside the shape is not a solution--it will be some of three dimensional polygon. Linear programming says the maximum must occur on the edges or corners of that region.

Comment: If you want to get exactly the right values, rather than just roughly, you can solve this by writing down a system of three simultaneous linear equations in thee unknowns. If you call $x, y, z$ the number of units of foods A, B and C, respectively, then your equations will be $10x + 5y + 20z = 1000, 20x + 10y + 40z = 900, 15x + 30y + 30z = 1200$. Usually there will be exactly one choice of $x, y, z$ that works, although the numbers might not be integers and they might be negative. This specific case is atypical, because there are no solutions. We say the system is *incompatible*.

Comment: As the nutritional values are a target, would those be inequalities? $10x + 5y + 20z \ge 1000, 20x + 10y + 40z \ge 900, 15x + 30y + 30z \ge 1200$ Also, negative values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ make no sense here. This all leads back to it being a linear programming problem.

Comment: Thank's everybody! That helps a lot. I think Arby and caverac are correct and linear programming is the way to go.